# Get program to return an error message and return to start of program if value entered is outside range

Tags: c, loops, if-statement

I'm a complete beginner with C and am currently trying to write a program where the user can enter results from football league games and calculate the teams' scores after each game.

There are 6 teams in the league and the user is required to choose a team at the start of the program in order to input a score for that team. What I would like to do is have the program return an error message if the user enters a value that is not between 1 and 6.

I've tried two different approaches but I'm not sure if either are in the right direction. One approach is shown below for the home team.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    int main(void)
{
    int h=0; /*Home team number*/
    int a=0; /*Away team number*/
    int hgoals=0; /*Goals scored by home team*/
    int agoals=0; /*Goals scored by away team*/

    /*User inputs home team number*/    
    printf("Home team number: ");
    scanf_s("%d",&h);   

    /*Returns error message if home team number is not between 1 & 6*/
    if(1<!h<!6){
    printf("Please enter a number between 1 & 6\n");
    }

    return 0;
    }
```

The other idea I had was to use an if statement where if the number entered is between 1 & 6 then nothing would happen, and use else to print the error message if the number is not between 1 & 6, but I'm not sure how to make an if statement that does nothing. I'm also thinking that I would have to put the entire program inside a loop to get it to restart if the number is not between 1 & 6.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: A loop might be a good start.

Comment: Yes, especially since you've already used the "loops" tag. There's a bazillion of C tutorials in the web, so just refer to the one you like most and learn about the different types of loops you can have.

Comment: What on Earth is this `if(1<!h<!6){` supposed to be ?

Comment: Expected that response. It was my attempt at trying to say if h is not within the range 1 to 6.

Comment: Ah, no range operators in C, use two distinct conditions and join them together with a logical or operator. Oh and you can use "goto" for your question too ... I think it might be a good idea if I run away now ...

Comment: Thanks for the help anyways, I'm actually getting somewhere with it now

Answer (score 1):

Change the condition in the `if` statement :

```
if(h < 1 || h > 6)
   printf("Please enter a number between 1 and 6\n");
```